# Socialenigne sign up stops working

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

In the log file got these problem

#2 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `en...', Array)
#3 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1076): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('engine4_user_fi...', Array)
#4 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Db/Table.php(149): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->insert(Array)
#5 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php(475): Engine_Db_Table->insert(Array)
#6 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php(446): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->_doInsert()
#7 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/modules/User/Plugin/Signup/Fields.php(257): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/modules/Core/Controller/Action/Helper/FormSequence.php(193): User_Plugin_Signup_Fields->onProcess()
#9 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/modules/Core/Controller/Action/Helper/FormSequence.php(45): Core_Controller_Action_Helper_FormSequence->doProcess()
#10 [internal function]: Core_Controller_Action_Helper_FormSequence->direct()
#11 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(328): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /home/imlink79/public_html/application/modules/User/controllers/SignupController.php(50): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->__call('formSequence', Array)

Comment: Some context would be useful, better formatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into following file, there you have query running:

> /application/modules/User/Plugin/Signup/Fields.php(257)

But if there is an error related to Insert query, you probably need to look to mysql log (usually located in /var/log/mysql) and find a log regarding sql-related error.